# Type conversion char to int to use as an index of a vector C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In my program I have a string of caracters that are all digits and I want to use them as indexes to get values from a vector. But the output of this code is a 15 digit number, so not **1** which is **vect[0]** i.e. what I thought it would output.

```
char c = '0';
vector<int> vect = {1};
int i = (int)c;
cout<<vect[i];
```

I have seen that converting from a caracter to an integer is done with

```
int i=(int)c;
```

So i really don't get how that is not an appropriate type for an index.

Comment: `int i = (int)c` does not results in `i=0`, but int `i=48`. 48 is the position of char '0' in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). You want `int i = (int)c - 48`

Answer (score 1):

First, it is bad practice to use C-style casts (`int i = (int) c;`), use a static cast instead (`int i = static_cast<int>(c);`). But indeed, as other mentioned, `char` are promoted to `int` automatically.

Then character '0' is not the same as the index 0. Have a look:

```
int i = c;
std::cout << i << std:endl;
```

If you want to use the character '0' as index 0, use:

```
int i = c - '0';
```

Comment: But since c is '0' isn't that always going to be 0?

Comment: There's no need to cast at all.  All `char`'s get promoted to `int`'s during arithmetic.  `int i = c - '0';` is all that is needed.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed.

Comment: @JohnCataldo depends on what `c` is going to be later? Otherwise, what's the point of the code?